# Assembling multiple Graphics objects

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Consider the following simple example:

```
f[x_] = Sin[5 x] + Sin[3 x];
p1 = PolarPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 50 {5, 2.5}, 
  Frame -> True]
p2 = PolarPlot[f'[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 50 {5, 3}, 
  Frame -> True]
```

which produces the following two figures

[image]
[image]

Now I'd like to align the two of them, one on top of each other, without any additional gaps. Doing `FullGraphics@GraphicsColumn[{p1, p2}, Frame -> All]`, returns an object with additional white space around the shorter figure (I've turned the frames on in all the objects to illustrate this)
[image]

I couldn't find a way to force each of the column "cells" to fit vertically to the image size (NOTE: I'm aware that in my example, there's additional horizontal whitespace in the second figure, and that is intentional. I'm only trying to fit it snugly vertically). I tried playing around with the `Spacings` option, but that's still not satisfactory. So, my first question would be: "Is there a way I can do this using `GraphicsGrid` or `GraphicsColumn` or by any other means?"

Another way would be to use `ImageAssemble` like so:

```
ImageAssemble[Map[FullGraphics, {{p1}, {p2}}, {2}]]
```

which does what I want, but gives a rasterized image (the following is a screen grab, as the saved file had much poorer resolution).

[image]

My actual figures are neat vector plots and I don't even want to think about rasterizing them, no matter how high the resolution. So, my second question would be: "Is there a way to get a vector graphics output from `ImageAssemble`?" If it helps, I'm using `Mma7` and saving my graphics as `Export["filename.pdf",expr]`.

I know that this is possible using `LevelScheme` for the example shown. However, not all plotting functions are compatible with `LevelScheme` and will not work in all cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the result have to be a graphic?  If not you can just use a regular column:

```
Column[{p1, p2}, Spacings -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: @Brett: That works neatly and exports well as a vector. Do you know why `GraphicsColumn` behaves differently? Is the behvaiour intentional?

Comment: I think `GraphicsColumn` is enforcing the `ItemAspectRatio` option, and I haven't found a way to turn it off.  (In fact I'm not sure why `GraphicsGrid` isn't running into the same issue.)  In general I like to use `Grid` more than `GraphicsGrid`.

Comment: @Brett: `GraphicsGrid` does have the same issue. See [this example](http://i.imgur.com/6xVDn.png) that I provided in my answer to Mr. Wizard.

Comment: @Brett `ItemAspectRatio` isn't even listed in the `GraphicsColumn` doc page. Isn't it simply related to `AspectRatio` (which is set-able) divided by the number of plots?

Comment: @Sjoerd `ItemAspectRatio` is what's causing the two framed sections in @yoda 's second picture to have the same shape, instead of shapes more closely following the shape of the individual graphics.  It's not documented, but is in `Options[GraphicsColumn]`.  `GraphicsColumn` and `GraphicsRow` are special cases of `GraphicsGrid`.  (Interestingly `Column` is related to `Grid`, but `Row` is not.)

Comment: @Brett: Does `ImageAssemble` always rasterize the graphics or can I override this behaviour? More generally, do the image processing algorithms rasterize graphics?

Comment: @yoda `Image` is inherently a grid of values, and so it will always rasterize.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Brett's answer, this might be what you want:

```
FullGraphics@GraphicsGrid[{{p1}, {p2}}, Spacings -> 0]
```

Comment: @Wizard: As I mentioned in my question, I did try playing around with the `Spacings` in `GraphicsColumn` (and `GraphicsGrid`, although I didn't mention this), but doesn't provide the compact arrangement as Brett's solution does. [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/6xVDn.png) an example that shows what I mean.

Comment: Or, perhaps? Spacings -> {0, -10}

Comment: @TomD: Then it becomes very subjective and I'd have to play around and find the sweet spot every time. Also, it doesn't solve the problem entirely. If you eliminate the spacing in-between by bringing them closer, it increases the whitespace at the top & bottom.

Comment: @yoda, you said: "returns an object with additional white space around the shorter figure" and I thought this improved that.  I agree that if you do not _need_ to use GraphicsGrid/GraphicsColumn that the generic forms (Grid/Column) usually work better.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

- Use `ImageAssemble[{image1},{image2}....]`.
- Can use `ImagePad` to add some space around each image:

  ```
  ImageAssemble[ {ImagePad[image1,m1]}, {ImagePad[image2,m2]},...]
  ```
- Note - all images must be of same size (Use `ImageDimensions`, and appropriate choice of `m1`, `m2`...).

**Method 2:**

- define an array of images of dimension rows x cols, say "myphotos"

  `ImageAssemble[myphotos]`